# How to add a detailed if condition in a sproc?

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, conditional-statements

I'm working on a website in which I should take data from a user then show him the tasks he should make at the day based on his career info

I have two main tables at the database "Manager" and "Worker".

When the user enter his data, his returned id should show What his type is.
Then I take the id and the date and get the day's tasks.

What I'm thinking at is making a condition to check whether this id is found at the Manager table & if it's found it'll retrieve the related tasks, or else it'll retrieve the tasks related to the Worker.

But I never write a condition at a SPROC before and all what i find is if x = < > ... etc (which is not what I want).

SO, would it be possible if you told me how it's written or if there is any useful tutorials or articles that mentions similar situation ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT ManagerID FROM Managers WHERE ManagerID = @ID) BEGIN

    --select from manager tasks

END
ELSE BEGIN

    --select worker tasks

END
```

I think that's what you asked for, so now I'll add my own two cents. I don't know if you're able to edit the schema at all, but wouldn't it make more sense to put the managers and workers in a single table and add a type column? If you did it that way none of this would be necessary.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to mark the answer if you're satisfied.

Comment: I'm sorry my account can't yet make up votes, but you totally deserve it.

Comment: As for your decision, it's totally right but the situation is kindda more complex than that.

Answer (score 1):

your question is somewhat confusing in manner what you want to ask ..

i think you want to know whether your user(user_id) is present in your manager table or in your worker table ..

that you can easily find out by following query..

```
select 'Manager' as u_type from manager 
where manager_id = <user_id>
union all 
select 'Worker' as u_type from worker
where worker_id = <user_id>
```

so by the help of this `u_type` value you can easily identify that your user type information ..

After that as you mentioned it is very simple to take data by day wise...

this query you can use in stored procedure as

```
select u_type 
into l_u_type 
from 
(
    select 'Manager' as u_type from manager 
    where manager_id = <user_id>
    union all 
    select 'Worker' as u_type from worker
    where worker_id = <user_id>
)
```

where `l_u_type` is your local variable, will be of either `varchar2` or `string` datatype